# Максимально неприветливая метка

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

На мой взгляд, такие метки уже перебор. Я имею в виду вот это:

[`леньделатьсамому`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83)

Предлагаю удалить. Мнения?

Добавлю, что такое "метка"

> Метка — это ключевое слово, позволяющее отнести ваш вопрос в одну категорию с другими похожими вопросами. Благодаря подбору правильных меток другие участники смогут проще найти ваш вопрос и быстрее дать на него ответ.

Одна из функций - это быстрый поиск. Никто не будет искать вопросы по метке такого характера + она не несет никакой информативности, а имеет только негативную подоплеку.

Comment: Кажется достаточно просто удалить ее из вопроса. Когда я ее видел - она была только на одном вопросе.

Comment: А так, по-моему тоже перебор

Comment: @МихаилРебров 3 вопроса и ставит ее один пользователь

Comment: Ну систематично такое делать - точно лишнее. На это лучше модератору внимание обратить. Это явно противоречит `be-nice`

Comment: === удаляйте ===

Comment: @Zhihar лаконично, спасибо, за мнение

Comment: *Никто не будет искать вопросы по метке такого характера* — зато можно внести вопросы с такой меткой в игнор :)

Comment: А как еще сказать пользователю, что он м... малоопытный?

Comment: @DaemonHK тогда это не метка, а ярлык. Может ввести систему ярлыков и вешать на пользователей? Пользователи знают, что они _малоопытны_

Comment: Помнится видел метку [tag:ясъелбутерброд]

Comment: @Dmitry вы очень хорошего мнения о них. Ни черта они не знают

Comment: @DaemonHK расстрэлять? =D Пускай учатся, но если унижать, многие перестанут это дело и озлобятся на весь мир. А потом вырастет какой нибудь новый Джобс, а я потом мучайся с этими их операционными системами.

Comment: Тем не менее, подобная метка, может в более формальном стиле все же нужна. Вопросы вида "напишите мне дз по информатике" очень частые

Comment: @StepanSokol уже есть способы обратить на это внимание -> комментарии, голоса за закрытие (с отдельным указанием на учебную задачу), голос против. Зачем еще то? И так новички стрессуют. Вчера боролся с скринами в вопросе, долго, муторно, но пользователь понял и больше не допустит (я надеюсь) этой ошибки

Comment: @Dmitry и то верно

Comment: Чем метка от тега отличается? Или это одно и то же?

Comment: Ничем. В англоязычной версии они так и называются. И если вы посмотрите на ссылку, ведущую на список меток  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags , то там вы увидите `tags`. В данном случае это просто перевод.